# How does it work a Multi-Layer GRU/LSTM in Pytorch

Tags: python, pytorch, lstm, recurrent-neural-network, gated-recurrent-unit

I'm trying to understand exactly how the calculation are performed in the GRU pytorch class. I'm having some troubles while reading the [GRU pytorch documetation](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.ao.nn.quantized.dynamic.GRU.html) and the [LSTM TorchScript documentation](https://pytorch.org/blog/optimizing-cuda-rnn-with-torchscript/) with its [code implementation](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/master/benchmarks/fastrnns/custom_lstms.py).

In the [GRU documentation](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.ao.nn.quantized.dynamic.GRU.html) is stated:

> **In a multilayer GRU, the input *x<sub>t</sub>*<sup>(*l*)​</sup> of the *l* <sub>-th</sub> layer (l>=2) is the hidden state *h<sub>t</sub>*<sup>(*l*−1)​</sup> of the previous layer multiplied by dropout *δ<sub>t</sub>*<sup>(*l*−1)</sup>​where each ​*δ<sub>t</sub>*<sup>(*l*−1)</sup>​ is a Bernoulli random variable which is 0 with probability dropout.**

So essentially given a sequence, each time point should be passed through all the layers for each loop, like [this implementation](https://pchanda.github.io/MultiLayer-GRU-pytorch/)

Meanwhile the [LSTM code implementation](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/master/benchmarks/fastrnns/custom_lstms.py) is:

```
def script_lstm(input_size, hidden_size, num_layers, bias=True,
                batch_first=False, dropout=False, bidirectional=False):
    '''Returns a ScriptModule that mimics a PyTorch native LSTM.'''

    # The following are not implemented.
    assert bias
    assert not batch_first

    if bidirectional:
        stack_type = StackedLSTM2
        layer_type = BidirLSTMLayer
        dirs = 2
    elif dropout:
        stack_type = StackedLSTMWithDropout
        layer_type = LSTMLayer
        dirs = 1
    else:
        stack_type = StackedLSTM
        layer_type = LSTMLayer
        dirs = 1

    return stack_type(num_layers, layer_type,
                      first_layer_args=[LSTMCell, input_size, hidden_size],
                      other_layer_args=[LSTMCell, hidden_size * dirs,
                                        hidden_size])
```

```
class LSTMCell(jit.ScriptModule):
    def __init__(self, input_size, hidden_size):
        super(LSTMCell, self).__init__()
        self.input_size = input_size
        self.hidden_size = hidden_size
        self.weight_ih = Parameter(torch.randn(4 * hidden_size, input_size))
        self.weight_hh = Parameter(torch.randn(4 * hidden_size, hidden_size))
        self.bias_ih = Parameter(torch.randn(4 * hidden_size))
        self.bias_hh = Parameter(torch.randn(4 * hidden_size))

    @jit.script_method
    def forward(self, input: Tensor, state: Tuple[Tensor, Tensor]) -> Tuple[Tensor, Tuple[Tensor, Tensor]]:
        hx, cx = state
        gates = (torch.mm(input, self.weight_ih.t()) + self.bias_ih +
                 torch.mm(hx, self.weight_hh.t()) + self.bias_hh)
        ingate, forgetgate, cellgate, outgate = gates.chunk(4, 1)

        ingate = torch.sigmoid(ingate)
        forgetgate = torch.sigmoid(forgetgate)
        cellgate = torch.tanh(cellgate)
        outgate = torch.sigmoid(outgate)

        cy = (forgetgate * cx) + (ingate * cellgate)
        hy = outgate * torch.tanh(cy)

        return hy, (hy, cy)
```

```
class LSTMLayer(jit.ScriptModule):
    def __init__(self, cell, *cell_args):
        super(LSTMLayer, self).__init__()
        self.cell = cell(*cell_args)

    @jit.script_method
    def forward(self, input: Tensor, state: Tuple[Tensor, Tensor]) -> Tuple[Tensor, Tuple[Tensor, Tensor]]:
        inputs = input.unbind(0)
        outputs = torch.jit.annotate(List[Tensor], [])
        for i in range(len(inputs)):
            out, state = self.cell(inputs[i], state)
            outputs += [out]
        return torch.stack(outputs), state
```

```
def init_stacked_lstm(num_layers, layer, first_layer_args, other_layer_args):
    layers = [layer(*first_layer_args)] + [layer(*other_layer_args)
                                           for _ in range(num_layers - 1)]
    return nn.ModuleList(layers)


class StackedLSTM(jit.ScriptModule):
    __constants__ = ['layers']  # Necessary for iterating through self.layers

    def __init__(self, num_layers, layer, first_layer_args, other_layer_args):
        super(StackedLSTM, self).__init__()
        self.layers = init_stacked_lstm(num_layers, layer, first_layer_args,
                                        other_layer_args)

    @jit.script_method
    def forward(self, input: Tensor, states: List[Tuple[Tensor, Tensor]]) -> Tuple[Tensor, List[Tuple[Tensor, Tensor]]]:
        # List[LSTMState]: One state per layer
        output_states = jit.annotate(List[Tuple[Tensor, Tensor]], [])
        output = input
        # XXX: enumerate https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/14471
        i = 0
        for rnn_layer in self.layers:
            state = states[i]
            output, out_state = rnn_layer(output, state)
            output_states += [out_state]
            i += 1
        return output, output_states
```

So in this case each layer does its own sequence for loop and passes another sequence tensor to the next layer.

So my question is: Which is the correct way to implement a multi-layer GRU?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are misunderstanding the definition. The approach that you see in the lstm code, where each layer passes an entire sequence on to the next, is the standard approach for stacked RNN's - at least for sequence to sequence models. It's equivalent to `RNN(RNN(input))`.

It's also what the PyTorch GRU definition is saying, albeit, in a somewhat round-about-way. The definition is saying that for the `N-th` layer GRU, the input `i`, is the hidden state `h` (read: output) of the `(N-1)-th` layer GRU. Now, in theory, we could run all the inputs one at a time through all the layers and collect the outputs. Or we can do the entire sequence for each layer and only keep the last output sequence. This second approach should be faster, because it allows for vectorizing the calculations more efficiently.

Further, if you look at the link you sent with the two different GRU models. You'll see that the results are equivalent, whether you run the inputs through each layer one at a time using GRUCell's, or use full GRU layers.

Comment: Thank you! Now I see the processes I was describing were the same all along. I'll then procede taking as a reference the jit implementation. Thank you again

Answer (score 0):

In the Pytorch GRU Document, you would find that it contains an attribute named `num_layers` which allows you to specify the number of GRU layers.

If this answers your question as to how we apply the GRU layers practically?

```
>>> rnn = nn.GRU(input_size = 10, hidden_size = 20, num_layers = 2)
>>> input = torch.randn(5, 3, 10)
>>> h0 = torch.randn(2, 3, 20)
>>> output, hn = rnn(input, h0)
```

Comment: Thank you for the response, but no. I know how to use pytorch GRU, but I wanted to know how to achieve the same results manually. I would like to know how the sequence points travel through the GRU structure, if they travel all through the layers and after that iterate or if the sequence is processed each time for each layer separately. Because in the link I shared it seems implemented in both ways and I wanted to know which one it is correct